# Options to insert data into mysql table

Tags: mysql

Hi I failed to find how to insert data into mysql database table using phpmyadmin on mamp. Neither found YouTube video or google tutorial as such. Is there any free tool/add-on to insert data into table? or my onlly choice is to use php script within the html code? Any suggestion on this? TYSM!

Comment: Belongs on serverfault? Not really programming related

Comment: Try Data Editor in dbForge: devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at HeidiSQL which is a handy free MySQL front end:

> http://www.heidisql.com/

You can create, browse and edit data. It also has bulk import tools to allow you to import data from CSV files or pre-generated SQL statements.

I find this a pretty invaluable tool for my daily MySQL management tasks.